# How to limit capture group options in Cucumber when passing dynamic parameters?

Tags: node.js, regex, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber

I am writing a test automation step-defintion using Cucumber and WebdriverJS. I have the following feature file

```
Scenario Outline : Validate whatever in this scenario works
  Given I have a <Service Method> for test store
  Then validate that something exists
 
  Example :

  |Service Method|
  |Carryout      |
  |Delivery      |
  |Dine-in       |
```

I'm mapping this cucumber step to the following auto-generated step-definition file

```
this.Given(/^I have a (.*) order$/, function (serviceMethod) {}
```

In this situation, I want this function to process only if the cucumber parameter is one of (carryout|delivery|dine-in).

I tried to limit the capture group by trying the following regex but the cucumber step-definition is not mapping to nodeJS step-definition after this.

```
this.Given(/^I have a (.*) (carryout|delivery|dine-in)? order$/, function (serviceMethod) {}
```

How can this be resolved ? Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Try  `/^I have a (.*?)(?: (carryout|delivery|hotspot))? order$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The query you had suggested didn't work for me. But this works for me now ```this.Given(/^I have a (carryout|delivery|dine-in) order$/, function (serviceMethod) {}```

Comment: Well, that is now unclear. The question looks as though you wanted to match an optional string.

Answer (score 0):

If you require one of those types of orders, you can speed things up by asserting it exists,
then laying down the blazay form of the container.

`/^(?=.* (carryout|delivery|dine-in) )I have a.*order$/`

Group 1 contains the *TYPE* of the order.

Answer (score 0):

`this.Given(/^I have a (carryout|delivery|dine-in) order$/, function (serviceMethod) {}`

The above step-definition finally worked for me.